# UIMenuController in a TableViewCell Element

Tags: swift, uitableview, uimenucontroller

I am looking to get a `UIMenuController` when an image within a cell is tapped. To be clear this is NOT when the cell is tapped, but rather when the image within the cell is tapped. The tap gesture on the image is firing off properly and running the function, but the menu never shows.

**Custom Cell:**

```
class VideoHomeCell: UITableViewCell {

    var thumbImage:UIImage! {
        didSet {
            createCell()
        }
    }

    private lazy var thumbImageView:UIImageView = {
        let view = UIImageView(image: self.thumbImage)
        view.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
        view.clipsToBounds = true
        view.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        let gesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(imageTapped))
        view.addGestureRecognizer(gesture)
        return view
    }()

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
    }

    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

        // Configure the view for the selected state
    }

    func createCell() {
        self.addSubview(thumbImageView)
        thumbImageView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100).isActive = true
        thumbImageView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100).isActive = true
        thumbImageView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
        thumbImageView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.topAnchor).isActive = true
    }

    @objc func imageTapped(recognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) {
        let menuController = UIMenuController.shared
        let trimItem = UIMenuItem(title: "Trim", action: #selector(menuSelected))
        menuController.menuItems = [trimItem]
        menuController.setTargetRect(self.thumbImageView.frame, in: self.superview!)
        menuController.setMenuVisible(true, animated: true)
    }

    @objc func menuSelected() {
        print("Menu Selection!")
    }
```

}

**TableView:**

```
override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return self.videoModelArray.count
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! VideoHomeCell

        cell.thumbImage = self.videoModelArray[indexPath.row].originalThumbnail

        return cell
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return 100.0
    }
```

I have tried different values within `setTargetRect` to include the gesture's view and self.frame. I have also tried rendering in self. Additionally, I manually set a `CGRect`. Nothing I do allows for the menu to display.

Comment: Try making sure the cell is the first responder before showing the menu.

Comment: Yes, I tried a `becomeFirstResponder` as the first statement in the `imageTapped` function prior. It didn't help.

Comment: @C6Silver try adding `override var canBecomeFirstResponder: Bool {
        return true
    }` to your tableview controller

Comment: @LeoDabus - Unfortunately no joy. Added to the TVC along with `becomeFirstResponder()` in the cell and still no menu shows.

Comment: For giggles I add the method to a UIBarButton I have in the table controller. It works there. Obviously not what I am looking for, but at least I know the function should be correct.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue by creating a protocol within the cell subclass and I assigned the table view controller as the delegate. When the image is tapped it fires off the delegate and then the `UIMenuController` is created within the tableview rather than within the tableviewcell. I pass back the cell and I am then able to use it's view to show the menu. It is also required to have the following on the tableview per Leo Dabus' comment.

```
override var canBecomeFirstResponder: Bool {
        return true
   }
```

In the end I while I was not able to make this work inside the tableviewcell subclass, I do find this an acceptable workaround.